# Como executar evento sem clicar inicialmente em radio button?

Tags: javafx

Como eu faço para fazer um evento de seleção de `radioButton` ser iniciado por padrão ?

Eu determinei que meus `radios buttons` vão chamar alguns métodos quando selecionados, eu fiz dentro do `initialize`, porém, da maneira que esta, eu tenho que clicar sobre o radio para ele executar, como eu faço, para que ele já dispare o evento ? eu já tentei dar um `radio01.setSelected(true);` porém ele só marca o radio e não dispara o evento.

```
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        fisica.setSelected(true);

        radio01.selectedProperty().addListener((p, ov, nv) -> {
            //metódos
        });

        radio02.selectedProperty().addListener((p, ov, nv) -> {
            //metódos
        });
}
```

Comment: Se ele será executado sem precisar selecionar o radio button então pra que colocar como um evento de select radio button? Não poderia somente sem um evento que inicializa normal?

Comment: @AndersonHenrique ele vai mudar os componentes da tela, ele tem que ter evento, pois quando selecionar o radio2 vai mudar a tela, sem o evento não da pra alternar pela tela pelo radio

Comment: Deixa os eventos e altera a tela na inicialização

Comment: Não tem outra forma, estou mudando os componente na tela, se for radio 1, é determinado campo, se for radio 2, é outros campos.

Comment: tenta usando bind().

Comment: @JulioCesar poderia me dar um exemplo ?

Comment: neste exemplo o button vai ficar `disable` dependendo se o tableView contem ou não dados. `btnSave.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(tbView.getItems()));`

Answer (score 1):

@G1Wing vai depender do que vc tá querendo fazer e no qual objeto, vc vai usar `bind()`. Para seu código funcionar vc deve arrumar o ordem da execução, lembre, o ordem de execução dos códigos é de esquerda para a direita e de cima para baixo.

```
    radio01.selectedProperty().addListener((p, ov, nv) -> {
        //metódos
        if(nv){
          //faz algo
        }              
    });

    radio02.selectedProperty().addListener((p, ov, nv) -> {
        //metódos
        if(nv){
          //faz algo
        } 
   });

   radio01.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: o resultado é o mesmo, infelizmente.

Comment: de onde vc tá querendo executar o radioButton???

Comment: initialize, eu deixo ele marcado já, porque quero a ação seja executa sem precisar clicar, isso na primeira vez

Comment: acabei de correr esse código aí e ele funciona:                                                `@Override
 public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        radio.selectedProperty().addListener((p, ov, nv) -> {
            //metódos
         if(nv)
         System.out.println("Pronto");
        });
  
  radio.setSelected(true);  

 }`